# DBF OLEDB C#: select with to_char

Tags: c#, oledb, dbf

Is it possible to do a to_char in a query with a DBF database ? It's not working and can't find the syntax on internet

This query not working, i have a message

> invalid function to_char :
>   SELECT t.*, to_char(d_volume) as d_volume_2
>                           FROM [deal] t

Thanks a lot

Comment: What DB provider being used? Try convert your DBF file and try the query again.

Answer (score 0):

You use whatever the source DB syntax is. To_Char is an Oracle function, try STR() function instead